# How to know which field is null in a row of database using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Do you have any idea how to know if a row in database is null.

I already tried `Model::find($id)->first()` and it give me the first result.
Now I want to know how to know which field is null and not null.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear. What do you mean by _row in database is null_? and a field cannot be null and not null at the same time. Are you asking how to add those constraints?

Answer (score 0):

`whereNotNull('field')` or `whereNull('field')`

Comment: thanks for this answer, im sorry if my question is not clear... but i think this is what im looking for